# Dual space of smooth functions on R

Tags: linear-transformations, dual-spaces, smooth-functions

How to construct an arbitrary set of linearly independent linear maps on $C({\infty})$ functions on R?

**My attempt:** 
I can choose S = {1, 2, ..., k} contained in R where k is arbitrary. For each i in S, I can create a bump function $f_i$ in a $\epsilon$ nbd of i. These functions will be linearly independent. Since k is arbitrary, $C^{\infty}(R)$ is infinite dimensional.

Now, I define $T_i(f)=\int_{i-\epsilon}^{i+\epsilon}{f_i(x)f(x)dx}$. Then $T_i$'s are linear and linearly independent. Just wanted to know if this approach is right?

Comment: Please add your attempts you wrote in the comments via edit to the original post,

Comment: Let me ask you this: why can you not tell yourself whether this works? Can you prove that $T_i$ is linear? For each $i$, can you come up with a function $g_i$ such that $T_j(g_i) \ne 0$ but for all $j \ne i, T_j(g_i) = 0$? (That isn't necessary to show linear independence, but it certainly is sufficient.)